# Ansible set environment variable from a file and access it within the playbook

Tags: ansible

I have the below Ansible script which runs on localhost

```
  - name: set env
    shell: ". /tmp/testenv"

  - name: get env
    debug:
      msg: "{{ lookup('env','TEST') }}"
```

In above script I'm trying to source the file and access the environment variables using the lookup. But it seems like environment variable is not set. Is there anyway I can get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

The shell command is one process and the lookup looks in the environment of the Ansible process, which is a different one. You have to echo the environment variable in your shell command and register the result.

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:

    - name: set env
      shell: "echo 'export TEST=test' > /tmp/testenv"

    - name: check env
      shell: ". /tmp/testenv; echo $TEST"
      register: result

    - name: get env
      debug:
        msg: "{{ result.stdout }}"
```